# Overloading a new operator - Shouldn't this code yield an error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand how the operator new can be overloaded and got this from the research I did online.
The new operator overload function takes in a `size_t` type. However in my `main` I am calling it using `new Dummy()`. From my understanding Dummy gets implicitly converted to size_t correct ? then what happens to `()` after Dummy ? shouldn't that result in an error ?

```
void* operator new(size_t sz)
{
  void* m = malloc(sz);
  std::cout<<"User Defined :: Operator new"<<std::endl;

  return m;
}

class Dummy
{
public:
  Dummy()
  {
    std::cout<<"Dummy :: Constructor"<<std::endl;
  }
  ~Dummy()
  {
    std::cout<<"Dummy :: Destructor"<<std::endl;
  }
};


int main()
{
    Dummy * dummyPtr = new Dummy();
}
```

Comment: "Dummy gets implicitly converted to size_t " - no, the size is the amount being allocated and is derived from `sizeof Dummy`

Comment: so who calls `sizeof Dummy` ? since the new overloaded operator only takes a size_t parameter how does new Dummy() get converted to size_t then

Comment: When the compiler sees a statement like `Dummy * dummyPtr = new Dummy();`, it generates code that is *equivalent* to the following (the real code is a bit more complex): `Dummy *obj = (Dummy*) operator new(sizeof Dummy); obj->Dummy(); Dummy * dummyPtr = obj;`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things involving `new` keyword:

First you have the `new` operator, there are different overloads defined by the standard and you can override them **or create your new ones**. It's responsibility is allocating memory of `N` size and returning a `void*` to it. You can even create your own `new` operator that allocates memory and gets an extra parameter like this:

```
void* operator new(size_t sz, char x) // x is a placement param
{
    std::cout << "User Defined :: Operator new" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new(sz); // standard new
}

auto* x = new('*') int(234); // our overload
```

But wait a second, how does the new operator get the size of the type we want to instantiate??

Our friend the `new expression` just entered the game!

Think about the new expression like some syntactic sugar for calling the new operator. It has this structure:

```
new(placement_params) type+initializer
```

it means that for `new int(22)` the expression will be `new(no placements) int + copy_initializer(22)` and it will internally call the `new operator` passing the size of the type.

New operator will return a `void*` that points to the memory that it just allocated and the right-size of the `new expression` will initialize that memory. In this example calling the copy initializer

Comment: thanks that helps could you tell me what placements are ? also in the example `new int(22)` could you explain how that works with the overloaded new function I am using ?

Comment: about placements and how to call them, check the first example (char x). For the case of `new int(22)` it will first call the `new operator` (the one without placements that you overridden) and allocate memory for `sizeof(int)`. Then it will initialize this memory with the copy_initializer(22) and return the whole `new expression` result as `int*`

Comment: A little confused here so for expression `new int(2)` if I have a custom operator overload with the signature `void* operator new(size_t sz)` how does my custom overload function get the size ? Does `sizeof(int)` get called automatically first and then the result of that is passed to my custom overload function ?

Comment: The compiler knows what type is being allocated with `new`, so it will supply that type's size as the `sz` value when it calls `operator new`.  Yes, it is equivalent to the compiler calling `sizeof` first and passing the result (though it doesn't actually call `sizeof`, since `sizeof` is always evaluated at compile-time, never at run-time, so it is a compile-time constant).

Comment: exactly, `new expression` is responsible of calling the `new` operator with the size (and it usually takes it from the type in the expression) @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0):

`new` is a language construct and not a regular function to it has special syntax and conveniences regarding its usage. There's differences between a [*new expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

The following both construct a `Dummy` but one uses local storage and the other uses dynamic storage. So in both cases `Dummy()` is part of the constructor call and, in the second case, not tied directly to `new`.

```
auto d1 = Dummy();
auto d2 = new Dummy();
```

Here the *new expression* both allocates space and constructs the `Dummy` in that space using the supplied constructor and arguments. The amount of space is determined by *the compiler* via `sizeof Dummy`.

When you overload the default `operator new`, it will use your user-defined function to do the allocation, but not the construction (that is done by the *new expression*).